# как получить данные асинхронной функции в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал изучать python, решил для практики написать бота для бинанс.
Удалось создать класс с асинхронной функцией, и получать данные с биржи, проблема в том, как правильно получать эти данные и обрабатывать

Вот код класса, который получает данные с биржи

```
class StreamDataConnector:
    '''Object constructor'''
    '''@.param symbol: str
       @:param interval: str
    '''
    def __init__(self, symbol, interval):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.interval = interval

        async def connerctor():
          
            url = f"wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams={self.symbol}@kline_{self.interval}"

            async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
                while True:
                    data = json.loads(await client.recv())['data']
                    print(data)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(connerctor())
```

Данные идут в непрерывном потоке

Я думал как то записывать в файл данные эти и читать этот файл параллельно, но это по моему не то. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильно делать, спасибо

Comment: По-моему, у вас проблема с методологией. И она отражается в постановке задачи. Сначала надо отвечать на вопрос: "Зачем и что делаем?", затем - на вопрос "Как?" Соответственно, вы-то что хотите делать с данными и зачем? Вам их надо долго хранить или нет? Как быстро их надо обрабытывать и какими порциями? И т.д.  Ответите себе на эти вопросы, возможно, и вопрос снимется. Не снимется - обновите текст вопроса тут. И при чём тут вообще асинхронность функции? Из обычной вы по-другому получать будете данные?

Comment: Лучше в БД писать, причём такую, которая многопоточность умеет. Файлы это не очень. Ну либо вызываете функцию в коде и получаете. Не совсем понятно в чём вопрос.

Comment: 'записывать в файл данные' как из многих вариантов, почему бы и нет. Какие есть алтернативы? самый простой вариант использовать списки или кортежи при желаний можео сахронить на диск или на облоко, самый продвинутый вариант использовать базы данных. В конечномом итоге этом вам решать, а не соседу Васе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то речь о том, чтоб разделить программу на два компонента:

1. коннектор, который в цикле читает данные
2. процессор, который получает данные из коннектора, и их обрабатывает

Один вариант, это создать асинхронный генератор:

```
import asyncio

class StreamDataConnector:
    async def get_data(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1                     # это имитация получения
            await asyncio.sleep(1)     # данных
            yield i

class Processor:
    async def process(self, connector):
        async for data in connector.get_data():
            # тут обрабатываем, в этом примере просто печатаем
            print(data)


async def main():
    connector = StreamDataConnector()
    processor = Processor()

    await asyncio.create_task(processor.process(connector))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Тут цикл, в котором `i` увеличивается на 1 и делается sleep имитирует получение новых данных. У вас в `get_data` должно быть то, что сейчас в `connerctor` т.е. открытие сокета и чтение, только вместо `print` делайте yield, как в примере.

Comment: да, то что надо спасибо большое